# Is it good idea to have mysql column names as numeric?

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql. I am going to read values from file and save into database using PHP. values in file are associated to specific integer number and can easily identified using that number. So will it be good idea to have column names in database as numeric ? I never used numeric column names before

Comment: No. Problems/solutions! like this are nearly always symptomatic of poor design

Comment: The whole history of computer programming entails the provision of names for numbers. Don't try to buck the trend.

Comment: Ick! [Code msell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is up to you (with [some restrictions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifiers.html)). But do you think that it is a good idea? If I would your colleague, I don't want to see `SELECT '122' FROM '223' WHERE '456' = 456` instead of `SELECT distance FROM places WHERE height = 456`

Comment: Welcome aboard, Viktor. This is great, and is all the answer that is needed. Even worse when it is not a colleague, but the OP himself who has to maintain the code :-)  Imagine if you wrote that, left it for 6 months and came back to it? Good luck!